# Include item only if not previously included with different metadata

Tags: msbuild

I have an MSBuild SDK that we use for our projects. We define various default properties and add custom items depending on the project type. Some of those items are added in the `SDK.targets`, after the user project is parsed.

I found a situation where I'd like to add some items but only if the user does not have them added themselves (to use whatever metadata values they have set).

Best way I found to achieve that is the following:

```xml
<Target Name="IncludeDefaults">
    <ItemGroup>
      <CustomItem Include="Foo" Value="Default"
        Condition="@(CustomItem->Equals('Foo')->Distinct()) == 'False'"/>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

I know I can exclude items using `Remove` but that only ignores exact matches, including metadata. I tried various other combinations of attributes and processing to get around that but nothing seems to have worked.

In particular I have multiple items to add with default metadata so I'm looking for a single line solution.

Is this the best way of doing it, or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have named data values and you want to provide default values if values have not already been provided.

Consider using properties.

The following example is very idiomatic MSBuild. The `Condition` tests that the property does not already have a value.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Foo Condition="'$(Foo)' == ''">Default</Foo>
    <Bar Condition="'$(Bar)' == ''">AnotherDefault</Bar>
</PropertyGroup>
```

In addition to `PropertyGroup` elements in files, properties can be defined by environment variables and by the command line `/p` switch so there is a lot of flexibility with defining and overriding properties.

But your question is about `ItemGroup` and I may be making an incorrect assumption about your intent.

`Remove` is for removing items that are already in the `ItemGroup` collection.

There is an `Exclude` that works with `Include` and behaves as a 'deny' list. In the following example if there is already a 'Foo' item in 'CustomItem', it will be excluded from the `Include`.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <CustomItem Include="Foo" Value="Default" Exclude="@(CustomItem)"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

The `Exclude` doesn't check metadata. It only compares the names. If CustomItem has items 'Foo' and 'Bar', then `@(CustomItem)` will be 'Foo;Bar' and 'Foo' will denied from the `Include`.

Comment: You are absolutely correct! I was using `Remove` when `Exclude` is what the docs were telling me to use. My mistake. Thanks for the excellent answer.